# Fail to log in to an encrypted home Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login, password, encryption, ecryptfs

As titled, I have problem in logging in to an encrypted home.

I have encrypted my home (admin) directory some time ago, so I don't really remember whether I written down the passphrase, but one thing for sure is that I am able to log in using some password into the home directory. I am pretty sure that I have never changed this password before yesterday.

Yesterday, I tried to share a folder from my home to another user. By stupid reason, I installed 'Users and Groups' for group management, and then add the other account to the same group as mine to see if we can share the data. Which turns out not working.(I wonder if it is the problem of the encryption now)

I thought it may be the problem of password, so I changed the password from 'Users and Groups'. Then log in the other account and see if that is accessible. (The answer is still no). Then I try to log back onto my own account, it accepted the new password, but flashes back to the login screen after that.

Being desperate, I log onto the other account and use sudo to change the password of my own account, also try to disable password there etc. Not a single method works.

Then after some searching. I think that it may be the problem of the encrypted home. Then I try to log in with command line, and tried to mount the home. But no luck. I tried to unwrap the passphrase, with all the different password that I have. (including the log in password I had for long long time). But it still got error of failing the unwrap.

What can I do to get back to the encrypted home?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Found a solution? Pls compare http://askubuntu.com/questions/682922/after-sudo-password-reset-cannot-longer-login